# On firebase dashboard not able to see older released version under 'Latest Release' section

Tags: firebase, mobile-application

We are releasing new version of the app frequently. But the firebase only shows one latest version and not the list of all previous versions.
Is there any setting for this?

Comment: Older versions of what?

Comment: Older version of mobile app.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of, but you can see previous versions if you head into the **Analytics Dashboard** screen.

There you will see many panes and one of them will show you how many users you have per application version.

If you click on it, you can see all the different application versions.

[image: Screenshot]